# beanstalkd interface/GUI

Tags: beanstalkd

Does anyone know of any interface to administer beanstalkd? What I'm looking for vaguely is something like PhpMyAdmin for MySQL.

Doesn't have to be PHP or web-based, could be any interface, GUI ..etc

Answer (score 8):

Just have found another one https://github.com/ptrofimov/beanstalk_console

Seems to be more functional and a little prettier.

Answer (score 3):

aurora: Cross-platform Beanstalk queue server console. (Zero-dependency)

https://github.com/xuri/aurora

Answer (score 0):

[phpBeanstalkdAdmin](http://mnapoli.github.com/phpBeanstalkdAdmin/) is based on PHP.

Answer (score -1):

Ahmad Amireh made http://github.com/amireh/Beanstalker but it requires some non-master code (it's waiting to become mainstream).

Answer (score -1):

[django-jack](http://github.com/andreisavu/django-jack)

Comment: I've just set this up and while it works ok I have to say that for what it does, django and python represents a huge amount of hassle to get it working.
I'm very tempted to write something in PHP that could be a lot simpler.

Answer (score -2):

Check http://github.com/earl/beanstalkc/blob/master/TUTORIAL which works great, although i'd consider it "cli" access at best